# date writing in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this code to write the date in a `csv` file (excel sheet) the code has no error but the date is not shown in the excel I need a read function but I don't know how and where in the code to use it.

```
 date=["16.02.2018", "blah"]
    CSVreport = open('indata.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(CSVreport)
    with open('indata.csv', 'w+') as CSVreport:
        wr = csv.writer(CSVreport)
        wr.writerow(date)
    CSVreport.close()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why are you opening the same file twice?

Comment: Please indent your code sample correctly, it currently raises a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The `with open...` syntax is a *replacement* for `open(...); close()`.

In addition, your code is indented incorrectly. Try this:

```
date=["16.02.2018", "blah"]

with open('indata.csv', 'w+') as CSVreport:
    wr = csv.writer(CSVreport)
    wr.writerow(date)
```